Unable to use auto-configured MockRestServiceServer since MockServerRestClientCustomizer has been bound to more than one RestClient | two Beans
I created a TestRestClient and it worked perfectly, but if I inject another RestClient bean into my RestClientConfiguration class, it works, but in the tests, it gives the following error: Unable to use auto-configured MockRestServiceServer since MockServerRestClientCustomizer has been bound to more than one RestClient.
Error message: Unable to use auto-configured MockRestServiceServer since MockServerRestClientCustomizer has been bound to more than one RestClient

my code: https://github.com/vitheka/doubt-test-restclient-with-two-beans
@RestClientTest({
        ViaCepApiService.class,
        RestClientConfiguration.class
})
class ViaCepApiServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockRestServiceServer server;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Autowired
    private ViaCepApiService viaCepApiService;

    private ViaCepResponse viaCepResponse;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {

        viaCepResponse = new ViaCepResponse(
                "88804-576",
                "Rua Albina Milanez",
                "",
                "",
                "Milanese",
                "Criciúma",
                "SC",
                "Santa Catarina",
                "Sul",
                "4204608",
                "",
                "48",
                "8089"
        );
    }

    @Test
    void getCep() throws JsonProcessingException {

        String baseUrl = "https://viacep.com.br";
        String path = "/ws/88804576/json/";

        var jsonResponse = mapper.writeValueAsString(viaCepResponse);

        var requestTo = MockRestRequestMatchers
                .requestToUriTemplate(baseUrl.concat(path));

        var withSuccess = MockRestResponseCreators.withSuccess(jsonResponse, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        server.expect(requestTo).andRespond(withSuccess);

        Assertions
                .assertThat(viaCepApiService.getViaCep())
                .isNotNull()
                .isEqualTo(viaCepResponse);

    }
}

